# Is this possible to configure WebStorm to start webdriver-manager to execute Protractor script?

Tags: protractor, webstorm

I am using WebStorm IDE to work with Protractor. So far, I am starting webdriver-manager from command prompt and executing the script in WebStorm.

Is there a way to start and keep running webdriver-manager from WebStorm itself? If Yes, Please let me know the steps.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure it as [**External tool**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2018.1/settings-tools-external-tools.html) in **Settings | Tools | External Tools** and then use menu action/assigned shortcut to start it:

[image]

If you don't like to start server manually, you can set up your protractor configuration accordingly:

If you have a standalone server installed, you can start it automatically by specifying `seleniumServerJar` in `protractor.conf.js` - see http://www.protractortest.org/#/server-setup#standalone-selenium-server, *Starting the Server from a Test Script*

Another option is using `directConnect` - see http://www.protractortest.org/#/server-setup#connecting-directly-to-browser-drivers

Comment: Thank you! I implemented your first solution. But, am getting following error when trying to run it: 

Error running 'webdriver': Cannot run program "C:\Users\A579418\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\bin\webdriver-manager.cmd" (in directory "C:\projects\RetailHSA\UIAutomation\ap118726-mm-test-source"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: when protractor is installed globally, the path to it should be `C:\Users\A579418\AppData\Roaming\npm\webdriver-manager.cmd`; `node_modules\protractor\bin\webdriver-manager.cmd` is only available in local installations. I'd suggest using ellipsys button next to **program** field to browse the executable - it should help to avoid issues like yours